# Prove to me with Hilbert's Axioms that rotations preserve angles and distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry

If I'm given the ERM (existence of Rigid Motions), how does one go about in showing rotations preserve angles and distance?

One of the methods that I had was to use sine and cosine, and those values are established in $\mathbb{R}^2$, by defining it as $c^2$ + $s^2$ = 1. But my question is to show preservation of angles, where would one go from here?

Comment: Do want $\Bbb{R}^2$ in the title?

Comment: Do a coordinate proof. Write the equations of two lines, find the formula for the angle between them, find the equations of the rotations of the two lines, and then show that the formula for the angle between those two lines yields the same result.

Comment: I think it's easier to prove those things for reflections, and then prove that any rotation can be written as the product of two reflections.